# problems with testing the Django REST Framework

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-tests

I'm trying to perform the tests that are within the Django Rest Framework documentation. And it always gives the same error, regardless of what I'm testing.

Test example:

```
class TestRequestFactory(APITestCase):

    def test_request(self):
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        request = factory.post('/list_user/', json.dumps({'title': 'new idea'}), content_type='application/json')
```

The error I'm referring to is this

```
 django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "user" does not exist LINE
 1: ...ted_by", "user"."created_ts", "user"."is_active" FROM "user"
```

I've looked in many places and the solution has always been the same, do `manage.py migrate` or `manage.py migrate --fake bots zero`, I can do everything, but in the end it gives the same error

Comment: Please include the views for the `/list_user/` route.

Comment: What is this `bots` you refer to.  What tutorial are you following.  The error you are showing is simply from a model that doesn't exist and/or isn't migrated.  `created_ts` is not a standard django user field, nor is `created_by`.  You are going to need to provide a lot more context.

Comment: Please add more clarity to your question.